# Openpyxl не записываются данные

Tags: excel, pycharm, openpyxl

Из данных одной таблицы создаю массив и пытаюсь записать в другой файл.

```
    pgb.create_sheet(title = 'Первый лист', index = 0)
    sheet = pgb['Первый лист']
    for row in range(1, rowm//4):
        for col in range(1, colm//4):
            value = str(row) + str(col)
            cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=col)
            cell.value = value
    pgb.close()
```

однако в файле только пустой лист, хотя чтение первого осуществляется